# how to display the content of given url in window application with c#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get the http request header and also the post data from a given URL.... how to do that?.... I have to display http request header, http response header, content of a given url and post data...

Below is my code for that....

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {

                string url = txtUrl.Text;

                HttpWebRequest WebRequestObject = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);




                HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)WebRequestObject.GetResponse();
                HttpStatusCode code = Response.StatusCode;
                txtStatus.Text = code.ToString();
                txtResponse.Text = Response.Headers.ToString();
                // Open data stream:
                Stream WebStream = Response.GetResponseStream();

                // Create reader object:
                StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(WebStream);

                // Read the entire stream content:
                string PageContent = Reader.ReadToEnd();

                // Cleanup
                Reader.Close();
                WebStream.Close();
                Response.Close();

                txtContent.Text = PageContent;

                //  var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.livescore.com ");
                //var response = request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

But how to get post data and http request header that i dont know...pls help

Comment: You have the request header as part of your `WebRequestObject`.  It looks like you are making a `GET` request, not a `POST`.  So you then want the response and the response header from the `GET`?

Comment: I am new to http request and respone..so no much idea...pls give suggestion what to do

Comment: Can any one give link for better ideas

Comment: I want to use the post method

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are trying to accomplish with mixed references to `GET`, `POST`, and request and response headers.

If you can make the request you want in a browser and use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) to intercept it, you can use the Fiddler add-on [Request-To-Code](http://www.chadsowald.com/software/fiddler-extension-request-to-code) to generate C# code that will perform the request.  The generated code would probably be a good place for you to start - from something that works and with which you can further tinker.

Fiddler is a *great* way to learn more about HTTP.